# bash alias с аргументами

Tags: python, linux, bash

мне нужно записать в .bashrc что то подобное:

`alias myc='source env/bin/activate && python src/main.py <аргументы> && deactivate'`

чтобы потом был возможен вызов скрипта таким образом:

`$ myc -a status`

Я пытался обернуть алиас в баш функцию и использовать "$@", но после непосредственно команды запуска вместо консоли я получал бесконечный инпут

```
$ myc -a status`
>
>
> 
...
```

Как мне правильно сделать этот синоним?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Алиасы не могут вставить аргументы в середину команды. Если вы зададите вашу команду как алиас `alias myc='source env/bin/activate && python src/main.py && deactivate'`, то вызов `myc -a status` будет развёрнут как

```
source env/bin/activate && python src/main.py && deactivate -a status
```

Следовательно, вам нужна функция

```
function myc { . env/bin/activate && python main.py "$@"; deactivate; }
```

В этой функции аргументы будут переданы в `main.py`

Answer (score 1):

Или скрипт

```
alias myc='/path/to/script'
```

В скрипте:

```
#!/bin/bash
source env/bin/activate && python src/main.py $@ && deactivate
```

Аналогичный вопрос на англ. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter/60058354#60058354)